# Можно ли анимировать движение элемента без JS , если значение position не менялось?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

есть зачаток галереи с фильтрацией. Изначально показываются все фотографии, за это же поведение отвечает кнопка Show ALL, далее если нажать например Landscapes кнопку, остаются только ландшафты, и они моментом займут новые позиции и встанут под ряд. Элементы убираются с помощью display:none. Свойство position, я не меняю, но фактически элемент встает в новую позицию. Можно ли это перемещение сделать плавным? [Вот пример с которого я черпаю вдохновение](http://technext.github.io/photography/works.html), а вот моя галерея, где хочу реализовать подобное [моя галерея.](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-merkle-6tgvn)

Comment: код лучше добавить прямо в вопрос

Comment: `transform: translate()`

Comment: Плавности можно добавить если анимировать дополнительно min-height и margin.  Но в определённых моментах картинка всё равно будет скакать. В ряд стоят три изображения. Включены девушки. При добавлении ландшафта (5 изображений) картинки с девушками смещаются.

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать дополнительно оборачивать каждый тематический блок. Это избавит от перескакиваний.